# Airport extreme seems to place a limit on gigabit ethernet

Tags: ethernet, airport

I have a gigabit internet which goes into my airport extreme. Everything is working fine now except the fact that the Gigabit Ethernet port has a limit of 200mb/s when tested. If I plug the main internet cable into my computer and test the download goes to 900+mb/s but when I plug it into Airport extreme and connect to it's (gigabit) ethernet I hit that 200mb/s limit no matter what.

I tried with different cables and whatnot, the ethernet is limited. Any ideas?

Comment: The APExisn't very strong in the gigabit area (see http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/32158-apple-airport-extreme-80211ac-reviewed for instance), but 200 seems a bit on the low end. How do you access the APEx from your computer for the tests, via cable or WiFi?

Comment: Without clarification of this point: is the computer connected to the Airport Extreme through the Wi-Fi or through the LAN Ethernet (or worse both), this question might be a false problem. The limit looks like the one on the 802.11n (450 Mb/s) minus the overhead to manage the radio level, the IP filtering and the NAT.

Comment: ` If I plug the main internet cable into my computer and test the download goes to 900+mb/s but when I plug it into Airport extreme and connect to it's (gigabit) ethernet I hit that 200mb/s limit no matter what.` - did you read the thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of pulling my hair out I'm going to answer my own.

TL; DR: Airport Extreme (at least the 2013 edition which I own) is crap for gigabit networks.

It's advertised gigabit ports cannot go over, after much testing, 205mb/s because of the WAN to LAN routing which is horrible.

This is a decent wireless router but overpriced for what it offers in terms of range and Ethernet performance. If you buy a gigabit internet do not make the mistake and buy it because it can't go faster than those 200mb/s.

As I said, after much reading and testing, your best bet is with a device that has hardware routing and I strongly recommend you take a look at [this page](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/tools/charts/router/view) for comparisons of various devices in terms of "WAN to LAN Throughput".

I just ordered a ASUS RT-AC87U which seems to offer a great signal and solve my gigabit issues. I will update this answer once I receive it and manage to do some testing.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same model that you, and your are partially wrong.

I got speeds between 215 and 235mb/s on PPPoE mode, but I got 300mb/s (my cable connection speed limit) on NAT and DHCP modes. Haven't tested it on VPN Passthrough mode.

All test with CAT.6 cable.

Comment: that's far from gigabit

Comment: As I said, it's my connection limit, and it's faster that you mention before.

Comment: I posted a link in my answer with a comparison and Airport Extreme seems to cap at 325 Mb/s. The remainder may be due to the fact that my cable is quite long and somewhat low quality even though with the same wire I get 900+ on direct mode. Both on PPPoE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Cablevision came today and upgraded me from 100mbps service to 300mbps service. I got 300+ directly out of the cable modem, but as soon as I hooked up the Airport Extreme, I could get no more than 100mbps, ethernet or wifi.

Eventually figured it was a router issue, so I called Apple and after getting sent to Level 1 tech support, did hard resets, upgraded, then downgraded firmware, tried a dozen different things. Nothing. It was elevated to Engineering, and I was told to expect to hear from them next week.

After a bit of thought, I suspected my ethernet was being capped at 100base-t, so started considering how I could test that. Suddenly I remembered that back in the day, the switch always had to be connected to WAN/cable modem via a crossover cable. Hm.

Dug in my ancient wire nest in the basement and found a crossover cable. Connected the cable modem to the Airport with it. Bam. 300mbps at the desktop, ether and wifi. 300mbps to my PHONE.

I don't know what the issue that makes this necessary but a crossover cable is a quick (and for me permanent) fix.